# Initialize Spring embedded database after deployment

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hsqldb

I have an Spring MVC app with an embedded database (HSQLDB) that I want to initialize after deployment. I know that I could use an xml script to define initial data for my datasource but, as long I'm using JPA + Hibernate, I would like to use Java code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavily updated answer (it was too complex before):

All you need is to add initializing bean to your context, which will insert all the necessary data into the database:

```
public class MockDataPopulator {

    private static boolean populated = false;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void populateDatabase() {
        // Prevent duplicate initialization as HSQL is also initialized only once. Duplicate executions 
        // can happen when the application context is reloaded - e.g. when running unit tests).
        if (populated) {
            return;
        }
        // Create new persistence session
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);
        // Insert mock entities
        session.merge(MockDataFactory.createMyFirstObject())
        session.merge(MockDataFactory.createMySeconfObject())
        // ...
        // Flush and close
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        // Set initialization flag
        populated = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, that is too much to add just some records. I thought that Spring would have something like ServletContextListener to know if all is ready to work with. Thanks anyway for you great answer.

Comment: Well, it is not too much. I probably made it look too complex. All you need is to create a single `InitializingBean` (or bean with `@PostConstruct`), which will initialize the data. We are generating also database schema on the fly in our application... that is part of the complexity above. Maybe I should rewrite my answer to keep things simple.

Comment: Ok... I've removed copy-and-paste code from our application and written the simplest example there is. Sorry for the previous complex mess :).

Comment: I like this: you can add objects instead of running scripts. When used for testing, your test won't break when the mapping changes.